# Show that $f(x,y)$ is discontinuous at the point $(1,2)$

Tags: limits, continuity

Let $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} & 2xy, \text{   if }(x,y) \neq (1,2) \\ & 0, \text{if    } (x,y)=(1,2) \end{cases}$

I have to prove that the function is discontinuous at $(1,2)$. I can see from simple observation that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} f(x,y)=4$, however, I have been unable to prove this via definition.

I need to prove that $|f(x,y)-4|\leq \alpha |x-1| + \beta |y-2|$ or $|f(x,y)-4|\leq \alpha |x-1| |y-2|$, so that I can get suitable $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, however, I have been unable to do this.

I get $|f(xy)-4|=2|xy-2| $. I don't know how to proceed from here.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**other**

Let

$$x_n=1+\frac 1n, y_n=2+\frac 1n.$$
we have
$$f(x_n,y_n)=4+2(\frac 3n +\frac{1}{n^2}),$$

$$(x_n,y_n)\to (1,2),$$
$$f(x_n,y_n)\to 4$$
and
$$f(1,2)=0\ne 4$$
then $f$ is not ...

Answer (score 3):

In problems like these it is useful to approach the point in question via different directions. In many cases, if there is a discontinuity, it will emerge in this way. Here, for example, if we look at the line $y=2x$, and take a sequence of points along this line tending to the point $(1,2)$, we find that the value of $f(x,y)$ along this line is $2x(2x)=4x^2$, which tends to $4$ when $(x,y)$ tends to $(1,2)$. Since the value of $f$ at $(1,2)$ is not equal to this limit, i.e., to $4$, we get a discontinuity.